# El resultado de la ecuación de segundo grado devuelve -1.#IND

Tags: c, ecuacion-cuadratica

Haciendo un ejercicio en C, meto los valores de las variables por teclado y me da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
Introduzca el valor del numero a:
4
Introduzca el valor del numero b:
5
Introduzca el valor del numero c:
6
El resultado es +/- -1.#IND
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
/* raiz cadrada.c*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
float a, b, c, resultado;
printf("Introduzca el valor del numero a: \n");
scanf("%f",&a);
printf("Introduzca el valor del numero b: \n");
scanf("%f",&b);
printf("Introduzca el valor del numero c: \n");
scanf("%f",&c);
resultado = (-b)+(sqrt(((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a));
printf("El resultado es +/- %g", resultado);

}
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?

Comment: no me había dado cuenta, muchisimas gracias :)

Comment: Te podría convenir tener dos resultados `resultado1 = -b + sqrt (b * b - 4 * a * c) / (2 * a);` y `resultado2 = -b - sqrt (b * b - 4 * a * c) / (2 * a);`

Comment: Borré mi comentario porque la solución no es el valor absoluto. Debés tener en cuenta que _la raíz cuadrada de un número negativo es un valor indeterminado_.

Comment: @IB podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para darle solución a una **ecuación cuadrática** o de **segundo grado** lo primero que debes hacer es hallar el **Determinante**, si el **Determinante es 0**, quiere decir que la ecuación tiene una sola solución, si el **Determinante es mayor a 0** quiere decir que la ecuación tiene dos soluciones, y si el **Determinante es menor que 0** quiere decir que la ecuación no tiene solución en el dominio de los números reales, pero si la tiene en el dominio de los números complejos (Pero esto ya son cuestiones matemáticas un poco más avanzadas).

La fórmula del **Determinante** es la siguiente:

```
D = b^2 - 4*a*c
```

Por tanto tu código quedaría como:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   float a, b, c, Determinante, X1, X2;

   printf("Introduzca el valor del número a: \n");
   scanf("%f",&a);

   printf("Introduzca el valor del número b: \n");
   scanf("%f",&b);

   printf("Introduzca el valor del número c: \n");
   scanf("%f",&c);

   //Calculamos el Determinante
   Determinante = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);

   if(Determinante < 0)
   {
      printf("La ecuación cuadrática no tiene solucición");
   }
   else if(Determinante == 0)//Solo hay una solución
   {
      X1 = -b / 2 * a;
      printf("La única solución de la ecuación cuadrática es: %g", X1);
   } 
   else if(Discriminante > 0)//Hay dos soluciones
   {
      X1 = (-b + sqrt(Discriminante)) / 2 * a;
      X2 = (-b - sqrt(Discriminante)) / 2 * a;
      printf("La primera solución de la ecuación cuadrática es: %g", X1);
      printf("La segunda solución de la ecuación cuadrática es: %g", X2);
   }
}
```

En este código lo primero que se hace es calcular el **Determinante**, en dependencia a si su valor es **negativo**, **positivo** o **0**, se hacen los cálculos correspondientes para hallar la solución o soluciones a la ecuación cuadrática.